# Does DynamoDB works in GAE?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, amazon-dynamodb

GAE needs some specifics library for S3 (jclouds or simple-s3 for instance), what about DynamoDB?

Comment: The DynamoDB API works completely over HTTP/HTTPS. So, I expected it might work right away using the URLFetch service. On the other hand, I found a [github project](https://github.com/apcj/aws-sdk-for-java-on-gae) and this [blog](http://apetresc.wordpress.com/2010/11/03/next-steps-in-gae-aws-sdk/). Both provide a forked AWS SDK for GAE.

You should also consider the bandwidth implications. If you are using DynamoDB in GAE you will pay for the bandwidth from GAE to DynamoDB. Your requests to DynamoDB will come from outside of the AWS datacenter, so the latency will be bigger.

Comment: If you like it, feel free to upvote it :)

Comment: Try to use [jcabi-dynamo](http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-dynamo/index.html) as a Java object layer on top of DynamoDB SDK